# Cannot WebScrape text from image link

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, alfresco-webscripts

I cannot able to webscrape rating percentage from amazon product page. I am getting only null values. Here is my code

```
from typing import Text
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import os

url='https://www.amazon.in/dp/B09BJQCTMX?ref=myi_title_dp'
req = requests.get(url)
content=BeautifulSoup(req.content,"lxml")
data = content.findAll('a',class_='a-link-normal')
print(data)
```

I have provided correct class name but only null values in retrieved.

Comment: Try printing `req.text`. It will print whole html page, In that big string, if your required data is present then you can access particular data using `bs4`. If not then you need to use other way

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to put `headers` inside request call and data will be present inside `content`

```
headers={"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36"}
url='https://www.amazon.in/dp/B09BJQCTMX?ref=myi_title_dp'
req = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
content=BeautifulSoup(req.content,"lxml")
```

Now use appropriate `class` to find data

```
text_data=content.find("span",class_="a-list-item").get_text(strip=True)
href_data=content.find("span",class_="a-list-item").find("a")['href']
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Can we webscrap a flipkart seller portal (after login)?

Comment: You can do that but you have to pass credentials and have to authenticate so look for that

Comment: Can you provide link for the resource where i can learn the necessary concept.